Different versions in one document Compatibility of TeX and derivates. ....To choose or not to choose
In another forum I once asked, if LaTeX is still compatible with TeX. I got the answer, that there is no problem as compatibility.
Well, the truth is quite different:
I cannot compile TeX files with LaTeX; I cannot compile LaTeX files with TeX...and so on.
The admirable TeX-concept is endangered by being split into variations of good, but separate versions.
Would it not be time, to get it all together again?
Short example:
%to be compiled with TeX

\newcount\version
\version=0
\ifnum\version=0{It is \TeX} 

I now will use the TeX commands.

\version=1
\ifnum\version=1{It is LaTeX} 

I now will use the LaTeX commands

\version=2

\ifnum\version=2{It is LuaTeX}

I now will use the LuaTeX commands

\fi\fi\fi
       
..and so on.
\bye

Wouldn't it be the right thing to do, to demand from all the authors compatibility in all of their packages, files or styles?
For me, it is a kind of false request, if I am told to use the version, the author has given.
As an example:
If an author writes
\def\pinguine{{\bf A bird in the Antarctic Circle}}

He also has to write:
\newcommand\pinguine{\textbf{A bird in the Antarctic Circle}}

and so on.
To be clear: I know, that LaTeX and derivatives are grown wide over this idea.
But I think, it is time to take a step back, to get forward.
The wit is, not to force the users to choose, before they are decided.

I've edited your question to correct some of the errors and to clarify what I think you are trying to ask. obviously, you are free to roll back my changes if you object. but I encourage you not to replace the first sentence. either your question is provocative or it isn't. saying it shall be provocative is only needed if you're concerned it otherwise won't be. note that I don't understand the final paragraph well enough to make an attempt at clarification.

Please don't downvote below a score of -1, even if the question in its current form needs some improvement. A score of -1 is enough to show that the question needs work, anything below that is of no use. Also, if you downvote or vote to close, please leave a comment explaining why you did so, but wait at least 24 hours after asking the OP for improvements to the question before voting to close.

latex is written in TeX so "compatibility" is not really a concept that applies. It is like asking if a python program is compatible with python.

@DavidCarlisle but which version?

@cfr well true I suppose (badly worded example on my part)

This question rests on a misconception (or several misconceptions) which may be worth addressing, whether the intention was simply to troll or not.

I got the answer, that there is no problem as compatibility.

This is true. TeX was designed to ensure that a .tex file which compiled when TeX was created would produce the same output anywhere and anytime TeX was available. That remains true.

I cannot compile TeX files with LaTeX; I cannot compile LaTeX
files with TeX...and so on.

Also true.

The admirable TeX-concept is endangered by being split into
variations of good, but separate versions.

This is a fundamental misunderstanding of 'the TeX concept'. The intention was never that all documents based on the TeX system should compile with all extensions of that system.

Would it not be time, to get it all together again?

That is, there is no 'again'. There was no Golden Age of the kind you propose returning to.
You have tagged your question core, but no section of your example can be compiled with core TeX alone. Core TeX does not define \TeX, for instance. Nor does it define \bf. These are defined in the plain format which is a set of macros built on top of core TeX.
No real document has ever been compiled using core TeX alone. The TeX Book, for example, uses plain etc.
plain is one format1 built on top of TeX. Knuth did not intend it to be the only one. The TeX Book says time and again that people will want to create formats for their own needs.
If anything, I suspect that Knuth was surprised that plain was used so widely. He clearly expected that formats would vary from institution to institution (since institutional access was the only way to get access to TeX at all).
In order to actually typeset anything, you have to extend TeX. At the very least, you have to set up fonts etc. Knuth intended plain to be an example, as well as a format people could use as-was. He intended people to develop other formats.
So optex, context, latex, platex and all the rest are absolutely true to the original vision of TeX's designer. Perhaps you would have had a different vision. Perhaps you don't like this variety. In that case, you don't like the very idea of TeX. You are entitled, obviously, not to like it, but don't make the mistake of thinking it is only the later developments to which you object. You object to the core design concept at the heart of TeX itself.
What Knuth may not have anticipated was the need to extend the core system by adding additional primitives, for example, and relaxing some of the system's initial constraints. eTeX is accepted as a legitimate extension, though engines must be able to run without the extensions if they are to qualify as TeX.
But the difference which the engine2 makes to what counts as valid markup at the document level are trivial in comparison with the difference the format makes. That is, the variety you dislike is almost entirely due to format differences, which TeX was designed to accommodate and encourage from its very inception.
1A format is basically a set of macros, hyphenation patterns etc. which is pre-compiled so that it can be loaded much faster when TeX runs. plain, optex, latex and context are examples, but there are many others. They are all built on top of core TeX or, in many cases, eTeX.
2An engine is a binary which compiles the source to produce the output. TeX, pdfTeX, luaTeX and XeTeX are engines. conTeXt (largely) determines the engine, but the other formats are generally compatible with all engines. Hence, latex, pdflatex, lualatex, xelatex and tex, pdftex, luatex, xetex etc.


++ Excellent coherent answer to an incoherent question

@cfr Please delete your answer and comments, so I can delete the question.

@MBE there's no need to delete here I think. The question and answer may be useful to others so why delete them?

@David Carlisle The question has lead to something, I did not intend. I will post another, maybe clearer question.

@MBE that happens but it does not mean that the question and answer are not useful to others. People answering offer there time for free to help, it's kind of frustrating if you put time in only to have a question deleted. Sometimes it's necessary but not here.

@David Carlisle Ok, I will respect that.
